# How to add inline listener in class properly?

Tags: javascript, class, listener

I am trying to add inline listener to the button in this case and I don;t want how to do this correctly, I want with paremeter but even it doesn't work without it:

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    document.body.innerHTML = `
      <button onclick="this.test()">click me</button>
    `;
  }

  test() {
    console.log("test");
  }
}

const app = new App();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside your inline listener is the button itself. You need something like this:

```js
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    document.body.innerHTML = `
      <button>click me</button>
    `;
    document.body.querySelector('button').onclick = this.test;
  }

  test() {
    console.log("test");
  }
}

const app = new App();
```